# Seque identifier in macos segue

Tags: xcode, macos, storyboard, interface-builder

In a macos storyboard, I have two view containers that act as placeholders for a storyboard loaded at runtime from a framework. The storyboard in the framework provide a prewired set of user interface controls with a controller class that are quite handy to have.

The issue is that since I have two placeholders for two identical storyboard reference, at runtime I am unable to know which is which...

**To give more details**

I have a view, that contains two viewcontainers, that are linked through an embed segue to two storyboard references.

At runtime, I can get to the loaded viewcontrollers in the function `prepare for segue`.

My issue is that I can't obviously distinguish between the two loded view controllers since they are an instance of te same class. I can't give an identifier to the storyboard reference. I tried to give an identifier to the placeholder, but I can't find a way to get to it in prepare for segue.
I tried to give an identifier to the embed segue, but all I get is an empty identifier in prepare for segue...

How then can I know which of the two loaded viewcontrollers is givent to me in prepare for segue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. It is a xCode 9 beta 6 debugger bug that led me to believe there was no identifier set. For instance :

```
(lldb) po segue.identifier
▿ Optional<Identifier>
  ▿ some : Identifier

(lldb) po segue.identifier!
▿ Identifier

(lldb) po segue
<NSStoryboardSegue:0x600000252630 identifier='SG1', source='<MyFramework.MyViewController: 0x6000000c2300>', destination='<MyFramework.NumericTableView: 0x600000106150>'>
```

So, there is an identifier set. lldb just fails to display it when requested.